# To find the approximate period and approximate equation of the limit cycle for a system with a Hopf bifurcation

Tags: nonlinear-system, chaos-theory, nonlinear-analysis

**Question:** The system
$$ \dot{x} = 3y + 3x^3 + xy $$
$$\dot{y} = -3x + \mu y + 2xy^2 - y^3$$
undergoes a Hopf bifurcation at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ as $\mu$ passes through 0. Calculate the approximated period of the periodic orbit created. Derive an approximate equation for the periodic orbit for $\mu$ small.

---

**Context:** For a related question, I placed the system in the form
$$\dot{x} = -\omega y + f(x, y)$$
$$\dot{y} = \omega x + g(x, y)$$
where $\omega = -3$, $f(x, y) = 3x^3 + xy$ and $g(x,y) = \mu y + 2xy^2 - y^3$ to calculate partial derivatives of $f$ and $g$ and hence the analytical criterion to show that the Hopf bifurcation is subcritical. Note **I'm not sure if this is relevant to the question above**.

The eigenvalues of the system are
$$\lambda_\pm = \frac{\mu \pm \sqrt{\mu^2 - 6^2}}{2} $$
which, for small $\mu$ becomes,
$$\lambda_\pm = \frac{\mu \pm i\sqrt{|6^2 - \mu^2|}}{2}.$$

---

**Attempt at a solution:**

Approximate the system as $\dot{x} = - \omega y$ and $\dot{y} = \omega x$. Then
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}} = -\frac{x}{y} \;\text{ so }\;  \frac{1}{2} \frac{d y^2}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} = -x.$$

Integrating both side with respect to $x$ and setting $C \in \mathbb{R}$, 
$x^2 + y^2 = C$.

Near the Hopf bifurcation the period of oscillation is 
$$\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{|6^2 - \mu^2| / 2}} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{|6^2 - \mu^2|}}. $$

I'm not sure how to find $C$ or $\mu$, or if instead they are meant to remain variables.

What is the relevance of $\mu$ being small? In general should this be $\mu \approx \mu_c$ where $\mu_c$ is the bifurcation point? I suspect $\mu$ must be close to $\mu_c$ so that the linear terms dominate.

Comment: Will it be helpful to convert the system to polar form? perhaps the links - [Link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995948/hopf-bifurcation-and-limit-cycle) and [Link 2](http://minitorn.tlu.ee/~jaagup/uk/dynsys/ds2/limit/Hopf/Hopf.html) may help, also there is a chat room dedicated to [Dynamical Systems and Chaos theory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory), although I admit that the chat room is empty.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try out that approach and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the analytical criterion mentioned above, we compute $a = 12$. Since $a > 0$ we have a subcritical (unstable) Hopf bifurcation at the fixed point $(x, y) = (0, 0)$. Also note that $\omega = -3$.

For small $\mu$, close to the fixed point, we can approximate the system as a pitchfork bifurcation with respect to the radius:

$$\dot{r} = \mu r + a r^3 = \mu r + 12r^3.$$
$$\dot{\theta} = \omega = -3$$

Hence there is a limit cycle at $r = \sqrt{\mu} / (2 \cdot \sqrt{3})$ with period $2 \pi / (|-3|) = (2/3) \cdot \pi$. In the coordinate system of the normal form, this becomes

$$ \dot{x} = \frac{\sqrt{\mu}}{2\sqrt{3}}\cos\left(\frac{-2}{3}\pi(t - t_0)\right)$$
$$\dot{y} =  \frac{\sqrt{\mu}}{2\sqrt{3}}\sin\left(\frac{-2}{3}\pi(t - t_0)\right)$$
so that in the coordinate system of the question (undoing the transform $y \mapsto -y$) we have

$$ \dot{x} = \frac{\sqrt{\mu}}{2\sqrt{3}}\cos\left(\frac{2}{3}\pi(t - t_0)\right)$$
$$\dot{y} =  \frac{\sqrt{\mu}}{2\sqrt{3}}\sin\left(\frac{2}{3}\pi(t - t_0)\right)$$